# How to Convert Sql to Dql?

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm

I have two columns in the SQL database which are 'start_date' and 'elapsed_Date'.  I need to check these two columns against the current datetime. I have successfully run the following SQL query against the database, but I need to convert the SQL query to DQL

```
SELECT*
FROM [DB_Name]
WHERE [start_date] < 'current_date' 
   AND 'current_date' < elapsed_date
```

I have tried to run this below but it has not given me the desired result:

```
    $query = $qb->select( 'ad' )
                ->where( $qb->expr()->eq( 'ad.status', ':status' ) )
                ->andWhere( $qb->expr()->lte( 'ad.start_date', ':sdate' ) )
                ->AndWhere( $qb->expr()->gte( ':edate', 'ad.elapsed_date' ) )
                ->setParameters( [
                    'status' => true,
                    'sdate'  => $qdate,
                    'edate'  => $qdate
                ] )->getQuery();
```

Comment: That query looks odd. Do you really mean to check if the literal string `'current_date'` is less than the value in the column `elapsed_date` or are you trying to compare the the value in the _column_ `current_date`?

Comment: You also seem to have different conditions (like `status` isn't mentioned in the first query). Please edit your question to be more clear. You should also include the table scheme, example data, expected output from that sample data and what you're currently getting. Currently, the question is too unclear.

Comment: i want to select records that falls within the start_date and end_date

Comment: Thanks its now working i swapped the parameters on the "gte" statement